# Wrong arguments (1 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a admin approval page for my posts and so far I have got the button and looking at another post I've updated my controllers to update_attributes. However when I click the approval button I get

> wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Here is where the problem is:

```
   def approve
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
     if @book.update_attribute(approved: true)
    redirect_to active_book_path
  else
   render root_path
  end 
end
end
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if @book.update_attribute(approved: true)
```

this should be

```
if @book.update_attribute(:approved, true)
or
if @book.update_attributes(approved: true)
```

check [update_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute) and [update_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) for more info